# Google People API - Field which shows how it was last updated - in Google itself, or via API

Tags: google-people-api

I have created a system where my clients' Google Contacts are synched with Podio CRM. When a contact is updated in Google, the contact is updated in Podio (and the flow stops at that point). When a contact is updated in Podio, the contact is updated in Google (via the people API), which triggers an update in Podio (not wanted!) - I would like to filter this action based on what was the last 'thing' to update the Google record (ie. if it was the API then the flow stops)

Comment: I'm afraid the field you are looking for does not exist in People API. Can you provide more details about the process in which an update in Contacts triggers an update in the CRM?

Comment: I'm using automate.io and the trigger is "New or Updated Personal Contact" - this then sends to a webhook in Podio, triggering Podio to request the details from Google Contacts and Podio then updates it's records accordingly. What I need to try and do is put a filter in automate.io to stop that process if it was updated via the API (ie. from Podio). In an ideal world if Google People API had push notifications this could be done in Podio but I don't believe it does...  You have to poll the API periodically and compare to see what's changed - not ideal for 7500 contacts and growing.

Comment: I guess there's no possible communication between both processes, so that you can pass some custom parameter to identify updates coming from the API?

Comment: I think even if I could do that, I'd have to essentially uncheck that box again afterwards (thereby triggering the update process) as if the contact was updated in Google Contacts rather than the API it would not update that field, so the filter would trigger but the field would still say it was the API that did the update still